# how can i remove onkeyup on my javascript code

Tags: javascript, input, ethereum, onkeyup

when i try to add a specific value with `value="444"` on the usd input it does not convert to the other value *eth* it's only working when i enter manually the amount. how can i convert when it's value already specified in the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="eth" class="currencyField" placeholder="ETH">
      <div class="arrow" style="margin: 0 10px";>=</div>
      <input type="number" name="usd" value="444" class="currencyField" value="" placeholder="USD">
    </div><span id="price"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(".currencyField").keyup(function(){ //input[name='calc']
 let convFrom;
 if($(this).prop("name") == "eth") {
       convFrom = "eth";
       convTo = "usd";
 }
 else {
       convFrom = "usd";
       convTo = "eth";
 }
 $.getJSON( "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=ethereum", 
    function( data) {
    var origAmount = parseFloat($("input[name='" + convFrom + "']").val());        
    var exchangeRate = parseInt(data[0].current_price);
    let amount;
    if(convFrom == "eth")
       amount = parseFloat(origAmount * exchangeRate);
    else
       amount = parseFloat(origAmount/ exchangeRate); 
    $("input[name='" + convTo + "']").val(amount.toFixed(2));
    price.innerHTML = amount
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        function getJSONData() {
          if ($(this).prop("name") == "eth") {
            convFrom = "eth";
            convTo = "usd";
          } else {
            convFrom = "usd";
            convTo = "eth";
          }
          $.getJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=ethereum", function (data) {
            var origAmount = parseFloat($("input[name='" + convFrom + "']").val());
            var exchangeRate = parseInt(data[0].current_price);
            let amount;
            if (convFrom == "eth") amount = parseFloat(origAmount * exchangeRate);
            else amount = parseFloat(origAmount / exchangeRate);
            $("input[name='" + convTo + "']").val(amount.toFixed(2));
            price.innerHTML = amount;
          });
        }

        getJSONData();

        $(".currencyField").keyup(function () {
          //input[name='calc']

          getJSONData();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

First of all, you must change the function out of `keyup`, because we don't do it. The function works when you enter value.